# PHP GD PNG Transparent black border

Tags: php, png, gd, transparent

i created some png images with php-gd.

This is Source:

```
border = imagecreatefrompng ("./images/border/platinum.png");
```

PHP-GD:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeGGI.jpg

it has some problems with unknown pixels.

how can i create original image with php-gd?

i succeed to do create image correctly, but i have one more problems

```
$lol_border = imagecreatefrompng ("./images/border/platinum.png");

imagealphablending($lol_border, false);
imagesavealpha($lol_border, true);

$lol_border_sx = imagesx($lol_border);
$lol_border_sy = imagesy($lol_border);

imagecopy($lol_bg, $lol_border, 0, 0, 0, 0, $lol_border_sx, $lol_border_sy);

imagepng($lol_bg);
imagedestroy($lol_bg);
```

here is my image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKQie.jpg

this image have black border on transparent

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: I didn't understand a thing. Let me suggest you put down some code, explain what you did, and what went wrong. 2 images like that make no sense.

Comment: @MihaiIorga here is my code..

Comment: Your argument is invalid. You can start reading [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesavealpha.php)

Comment: @MihaiIorga i have very long code, so i can't copy all of my code. sorry!

i succeed to do create image correctly, but i one more problems

$lol_border = imagecreatefrompng ("./images/border/platinum.png");

imagealphablending($lol_border, false);
imagesavealpha($lol_border, true);

$lol_border_sx = imagesx($lol_border);
$lol_border_sy = imagesy($lol_border);

imagecopy($lol_bg, $lol_border, 0, 0, 0, 0, $lol_border_sx, $lol_border_sy);

imagepng($lol_bg);
imagedestroy($lol_bg);

Comment: @MihaiIorga i posted problems, thanks a lot :)